# Django Serializer Nested Creation: How to avoid N+1 queries on relations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

There are dozens of posts about n+1 queries in nested relations in Django, but I can't seem to find the answer to my question. Here's the context:

**The Models**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Tag(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('app.Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
    category = models.ForeignKey('app.TagCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    page = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class TagCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

A book has many tags, each tag belongs to a tag category.

**The Serializers**

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        exclude = ['id', 'book']

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'tags']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
            book = Book.objects.create(**validated_data)
            Tag.objects.bulk_create([Tag(book=book, **tag) for tag in tags])
        return book
```

**The Problem**

I am trying to POST to the `BookViewSet` with the following example data:

```
{ 
  "title": "The Jungle Book"
  "tags": [
    { "page": 1, "category": 36 }, // plot intro
    { "page": 2, "category": 37 }, // character intro
    { "page": 4, "category": 37 }, // character intro
    // ... up to 1000 tags
  ]
}
```

This all works, however, during the post, the serializer proceeds to make a call for each tag to check if the `category_id` is a valid one:

[image]

With up to 1000 nested tags in a call, I can't afford this. 
How do I "prefetch" for the validation?
If this is impossible, how do I turn off the validation that checks if a foreign_key id is in the database?

**EDIT: Additional Info**

Here is the view:

```
class BookViewSet(views.APIView):

    queryset = Book.objects.all().select_related('tags', 'tags__category')
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Use the .prefetch_related() function to solve

Comment: @jbodily i know it's been a long time since you asked this question, were you able solve this issue without turning off the validation? Im facing this issue..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848305/many-many-nested-serializer-create-method-does-similar-n1-queries

Answer (score 6):

The DRF serializer is not the place (in my own opinion) to optimize a DB query. Serializer has 2 jobs:

1. Serialize and check the validity of input data.
2. Serialize output data.

Therefore the correct place to optimize your query is the corresponding view.
We will use the [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method that:

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.
>   to avoid the N+1 database queries.

You will need to modify the part of your view code that creates the corresponding queryset, in order to include a `select_related` call.
You will also need to add a `related_name` to the `Tag.category` field definition.

*Example*:

```
# In your Tag model:
category = models.ForeignKey(
    'app.TagCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='categories'
)

# In your queryset defining part of your View:
class BookViewSet(views.APIView):

    queryset = Book.objects.all().select_related(
        'tags', 'tags__categories'
    )  # We are using the related_name of the ForeignKey relationships.
```

---

If you want to test something different that uses also the serializer to cut down the number of queries, you can check [this article](http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/).

Comment: I have added the view to the question. I did as you recommended and added the prefetch_related to the view to get tags and tags__category (it's one-to-many), but on create it is still querying once per tag for the tag_category.

Comment: This should be done via a select_related, not prefetch. (Because it's 1 to Many and not Many to Many).

Comment: @yrekkehs You are absolutely right and that is the reason why one shouldn't try answering 2 in the morning :P. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @jbodily As yrekkehs caught my error, the correct method you should use is the `select_related`. I edited my answer and you should try it as it is now. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I appreciate the due diligence, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to help on creation. Let me clarify the relations again:  A book has many tags, a tag has one `book`. A `tag` has one `tag_category`, a `tag_category` has many tags.  So two one-to-many relations. There is no `tags__categories`. But secondly, I've updated my question to reflect your solution but still find that on create, the db is queried once per category.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been around for a long time, but I had the same problem and I was looking for the solution for several days, in the end I found another solution that worked for me.

I leave it here in case it helps someone, in this way it no longer makes a query for each relationship, now it is only a query for all and in `to_internal_value` it validates the foreign key

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    category_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Category.objects.all(), source='category', write_only=True)
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.categories = Category.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        category_id = data.pop('category_id', None)

        if category_id is not None:
            if not category_id in self.categories:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({
                    'category_id': 'Category does not exist'
                })
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that the `Tag` constructor is automatically converting the category id that you pass in as `category` into a `TagCategory` instance by looking it up from the database.  The way to avoid that is by doing something like the following if you know that all of the category ids are valid:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
            book = Book.objects.create(**validated_data)
            tag_instances = [ Tag(book_id=book.id, page=x['page'], category_id=x['category']) for x in tags ]
            Tag.objects.bulk_create(tag_instances)
        return book
```

Comment: This feels like it should be right, but check out the update I added: In the view I call serializer.is_valid(), then serializer.save(). The problem is on the is_valid check, if the category_id is set and not the category, it says `category: This field may not be null.`

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an answer that gets things working (but that I'm not thrilled about): Modify the Tag Serializer like this:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    category_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        exclude = ['id', 'book', 'category']
```

This allows me to read/write a category_id without having the overhead of validations. Adding `category` to exclude does mean that the serializer will ignore `category` if it's set on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you don't set created tags to the book instance so serializer try to get this while returning.

You need to set it to the book as a list:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    with transaction.atomic():
        book = Book.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Add None as a default and check that tags are provided
        # If you don't do that, serializer will raise error if request don't have 'tags'

        tags = validated_data.pop('tags', None)
        tags_to_create = []

        if tags:
            tags_to_create = [Tag(book=book, **tag) for tag in tags]
            Tag.objects.bulk_create(tags_to_create)

        # Here I set tags to the book instance
        setattr(book, 'tags', tags_to_create)

    return book
```

Provide Meta.fields tuple for **TagSerializer** (it's weird that this serializer don't raise error saying that **fields** tuple is required)

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('category', 'page',)
```

Prefetching tag.category should be NOT necessary in this case because it's just id.

You will need prefetching **Book.tags** for **GET** method. The simplest solution is to create static method for serializer and use it in **viewset get_queryset** method like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset): # It can be named any name you like
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('tags')

        return queryset

class BookViewSet(views.APIView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset = BookSerializer.setup_eager_loading(self.queryset)
        # Every GET request will prefetch 'tags' for every book by default

        return super(BookViewSet, self).get_queryset()
```

Answer (score 0):

`select_related` function will check ForeignKey in the first time.
Actually,this is a ForeignKey check in the relational database and you can use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` in database to close inspection.