# Many-Many nested serializer create method does similar n+1 queries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a many-many relation between User model and my custom Team model. Where i can add multiple users to my team. I have used prefetch_related on my team model so the get (list) operation is optimized, whereas the post (create) operations does query every time for a user. Below is my code.

**models.py**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.team_name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return [instance.id ,instance.username]

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=data) # this queries the db for every user
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User does not exists")

class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=UserSerializer(many=True) 
    class Meta:
        model=Team
        fields=('team_name','user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        users = validated_data.pop('user')
        team = Team.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for user in users:
            team.user.add(user)
        return team
```

**views.py**

```
class TeamView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Team.objects.all().prefetch_related('user')
    serializer_class=TeamSerializer
```

**input request:**

```
   {
    "team_name": "team1",
    "users": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

[image]
as it can be seen, for 7 users added to the team, it does 7 queries. how can this be optimized ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the point to add `to_internal_value` function I mean the serializer will take a `User` object from the queryset and will convert it to a JSON representation, Why `User.objects.get(id=data)`? The ViewSet will return the proper HTTP response if any object is not found or it doesn't exists.

Comment: when i call team api, it will return the username of users in the team. but to add new users (list of users) to the team, i'm passing list of user id's. which throws: invalid data expected dictionary, got int....so to handle it to_internal_value is used

Comment: @allexiusw, updated the question with input request.